# How te restart the sidekiq when it crushes down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, restart, sidekiq-monitor

I started the sidekiq by

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production
```

Sometime, Sidekiq was crushed, busy=0 and enqueue > 0.

How can I setup the sidekiq to restart after crushed/stopped?

Comment: You'll need some kind of monitor app, like `god` or `monit` or any other monitor you like.

Comment: I second monit it is great. However, systemd can also restart processes if your linux distro has it

Comment: [tag:CRUSH] is an acronym for Controlled Replication Under Scalable Hashing. It is the algorithm that drives the Ceph object storage environment.  it doesn't seem to apply here.  For the record, it's "Crash", not "Crush"

Answer (score 0):

You can use some automated packages, or write your own bash script to do that.

I personally prefer writing my own scripts so let me explain that:

1. Write a script that executes sidekiq *if not running already*
2. Write a cronjob to execute that script every minute

**Note that this method is not instant**, meaning that you might have a downtime up to 1 minute, since the cronjob works every minute. So if your project is sensitive on that, you might want to use one of the process management tools such as `monit` or `god`.

Your bash script should contain your command,

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production
```

But make sure you are using absolute paths if you are going to store your script outside your project directory.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c) is a helpful topic about writing the shell script to check whether the process already exists.

To run the script every minute, do the following:

1. Go to your terminal
2. Type `crontab -e`
3. Append `* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR && sh SCRIPTNAME.sh'`
4. Save and exit editor

By doing this, you are telling your computer to execute your script every minute.
Usually people prefer writing only `* * * * * /path/to/script.sh` to their crontab but this fails in some circumstances.

Hope this helps.